# How do you calculate gravitational acceleration from within a ring of mass?

Tags: gravity, acceleration

I'm trying to find gravitational acceleration from a point within a ring to the closer edge of the ring. If it matters, the ring has a much greater mass than the object inside. Since the object is inside of the ring, it will have a gravitational pull from all directions, but more toward the closer edge. I'm assuming there would still be acceleration to the edge, but I'm at a loss as to how to calculate it.

Comment: What do you mean by *the formula for gravitational acceleration*? Please specify what formula you are referring to.

Comment: You can see the formula for centrifugal acceleration here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force#Acceleration As you see it does not resemble that of gravity from a point source, or something else simple.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was looking at the point source formula.

Comment: What do you mean by "there are no outside gravitational forces applied"? How can you apply or un-apply a gravitational force?

Comment: It would be helpful it you could explain what your thinking is, ie how you think the *point source formula* might apply.

Comment: I think "no contact with the container" and "rotating at the same frequency as the centrifuge" are inconsistent statements, unless there is some other force on the object that you haven't specified.  In any event, as @Conifold has pointed out, the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very well thought out. The rotation isn't relevant. Basically, I'm trying to find gravitational acceleration of an object within a ring, towards the closer edge of the ring. If it matters, the ring has a much greater mass than the object inside. Since the object is inside of the ring, it will have a gravitational pull from all directions, but more toward the closer edge. I'm assuming there would still be acceleration to the closer edge, but I'm at a loss as to how to calculate it.

Comment: Yes, this is a much clearer question now. I presume you do mean a flat ring rather than a spherical shell - in the latter case the gravity force on an object at any point inside the shell is zero. See [Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) in wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, it's a flat ring coplanar with the object's center of mass. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Hi Scott, there is no acceleration in the ring.  Everything cancels.  I think you can see that at the center of the ring everything should cancel but it turns out, all points within the ring have the same cancellation and the acceleration is zero everywhere.  Even really close to one side of the ring.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, do you have a link to an example of the math? I can only find this effect shown within a shell (Shell Theorem), not a ring.